# MobileFirst InstallationManager hangs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-installation

Working on an isolated Linux machine, no internet access.

I am installing MobileFirst Server v7.0, WAS Liberty and IBM Java.

Having attached my repositories to Installation Manager I select an option to install. Click Next, and nothing further happens.

I see various solutions offered all of which are concerned with avoiding checking for update sites on the internet. I have followed all these, checked in the Installation Manager logs, see no error messages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using v1.7 of Installation Manager, installed as adminsitrator.

We moved up to v1.8.2.1 installed as our user. It now works. Whether that's a version problem or an ownership problem I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the Install manager upgrade if you use an HTTPS repository that has deactivated sslv3 -- see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688724